# Cycle through divs, fading out the previous while fading in the next div

Tags: jquery, slideshow, cycle

I already have the cycle through effect working just fine but I can't figure out how to fade in the next div while the previous div is fading out.

Instead, what I have is white space before the next div fades in.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Covanant/mhzn4/

The snippet:

```
var divs = $('div[id^="content-"]').hide(),
    i = 0;

(function cycle() { 

    divs.eq(i).fadeIn(3000)
              .addClass('animated')
              .delay(1000)
              .fadeOut(3000, cycle);

    i = ++i % divs.length;

})();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery crossfade without a plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5664634/jquery-crossfade-without-a-plugin)

Comment: Cycle is the callback function, it won't run again before the fadeout is done.

Comment: I wrote a simple fade function for [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16648084/jquery-fade-rotate-between-3-divs/16648755#16648755)